# how to set unix/bash as default language on notepad++ 6.5.5

Tags: bash, unix, notepad++, default

when going in settings> preferences> new document, which language should I chose to create Unix scripts (*.sh *.bsh).
I know that a solution is to chose the format when saving, but it's kinda annoying...
thanks!

Comment: Do you have "Shell" in the options list?

Comment: yes, should I set Shell?!

Comment: Yes, I do not have Notepad++ with me but I think this is the one that matches best.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Format: Unix/OSX

Default language: Shell

Encoding: UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of **Notepad++** -status bar- you will see that 7th and 8th columns are describing the format of the file you are editing.
[image]

double click on the 7th one and select "**Unix(LF)**" 
for the 8th one Go To: Encoding ->  Encode in UTF-8

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, they want to change the default language.

Comment: I know that but setting up default language in encoding will not complete the process. you still have to change the  Line Break Type to Unix(LF). that is the correct format for Unix/bash as it was asked in the question.  if you don't, Unix (or Linux) will give an error for every blank line.